# Why is it desired to have an aperture of a spherical mirror to be less than the radius of curvature?

Tags: optics, reflection

In many instances, I have noticed that it is given that the aperture is less than the radius of curvature for a spherical mirror. Why is this given like that?

Comment: The reason us not given in my textbook.

Comment: Had not the aperture been smaller than the radius of curvature, all the rays parallel to the principal axis, wouldn't converged to a single point which we call focus. That is the reason for this approximation.

Comment: It's okay. But I strongly refer to switch over your book & start reading some good book.

Comment: @user36790 Why did you post an answer as a comment? Just post it as an answer.

Comment: @DanielSank: Thanks, for the advice, sir. But I didn't want to put such a small line as an answer; I wanted to put a picture- a good picture that could interpret my argument. However, John Rennie is to the rescue!

Comment: @user36790 "start reading some good book" is terrible advice, clearly OP does not know that his/her book is "not good" to begin with. How is OP supposed to know what a "good book" is?

Comment: @0celo7: He didn't not know & that's why I advised him. Even a mediocre book does mention the reason for that approximation.And every standard optics textbook gives a good account of that. Now if a book is mentioning & using the approximation without citing the reason, then how could it be a `good book`?

Comment: @user36790 "But I strongly refer to switch over your book & start reading some good book." You need to tell him a good book to read!

Comment: @0celo7: Yes, I would if he asked. BTW, PSE offers good list of recommendations, too.

Answer (score 6):

Spherical mirrors do not focus parallel light rays to a single focal point. The focus actually lies on a surface called a [caustic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caustic_(optics)). [Wolfram have a nice demonstration of this here](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ParaxialApproximationAndTheMirror/).

[image: Spherical mirror]

Light rays close to the centre of the mirror, i.e. the region where the mirror is only slightly angled away from the vertical, do come to a single focal point to a good approximation. This is known as the [paraxial approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraxial_approximation). The point of using an aperture much smaller that the radius of the mirror is to restrict the incoming light to a region where rays do (almost) come to a single focal point.